# Installing android market on Emulator 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have to build an application which contains push notifications feature.I read an article given on net.I need to install android market on my emulator for that purpose.Can someone please guide me the procedure to install the android market app on emulator 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge installing Android Market application on Emulator is not possible at all.

For that you need to test your application on real device.

Comment: Great...I didn't know about it. That is why I said "According to my knowledge". :-)

Comment: No problem dude . I just inform you that it is possible .